# R - Delete Observations if More Than 25% of a Group

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidy

This is my first post!  I started using R about a year ago and I have learned a lot from this sub over the last few months!  Thanks for all of your help so far.

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

•   Group Data by POS
•   Within each POS group, no ORG should represent more than 25% of the dataset
•   If the ORG represents more than 25% of the observation(column), the value furthest from the mean should be deleted.  I think this would loop until the data from that ORG are less than 25% of the observation.

I am not sure how to approach this problem as I am a not too familiar with R functions.  Well, I am assuming this would require a function.

**Here is the sample dataset:**

```
print(Example)                                                                                                                                                            
# A tibble: 18 x 13
     Org   Pos  obv1  obv2  obv3  obv4 obv5   obv6  obv7  obv8  obv9 obv10 obv11
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1 34.6   26.2  43.1 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 2     2     1 18.7   15.5  23.4 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 3     3     1 16.2   14.4  21.7 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1.32
 4     3     1 20.0   15.5  23.4 NA    NA     1.32  2.78  1.44 NA    NA     1.89
 5     3     1  2.39  16.9  24.1 NA    NA     1.13  1.52  1.12 NA    NA     2.78
 6     3     1 24.3   15.4  24.6 NA    NA     1.13  1.89  1.13 NA    NA     1.51
 7     6     1 16.7   16.0  23.4  0.19 NA     0.83  1.3   0.94  1.78  2.15  1.51
 8     6     1 18.7   16.4  25.8  0.19 NA     1.22  1.4   0.97  1.93  2.35  1.51
 9     6     1 19.3   16.4  25.8  0.19 NA     1.22  1.4   0.97  1.93  2.35  1.51
10     7     1 23.8   18.6  28.6 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
11    12     2 28.8   24.4  39.7 NA    NA     1.13  1.89  1.32  2.46  3.21 NA   
12    13     2 24.6   19.6  29.4  0.16 NA     3.23  3.23  2.27 NA    NA    NA   
13    14     2 18.4   15.5  24.8 NA    NA     2.27  3.78  1.13  3.46  4.91  2.78
14    15     2 23.8   24.4  39.7 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
15    15     2 25.8   24.4  39.7 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
16    16     2 18.9   17.4  26.9  0.15 NA    NA     1.89  2.99 NA    NA     1.51
17    16     2 22.1   17.3  26.9 NA    NA    NA     2.57  0.94 NA    NA     1.51
18    16     2 24.3   19.6  28.5  0.15 NA    NA     1.51  1.32 NA    NA     2.27
```

**The result would look something like this:**

```
print(Result)                                                                                                                                                             
# A tibble: 18 x 13
     Org   Pos  obv1  obv2  obv3  obv4 obv5   obv6  obv7  obv8  obv9 obv10 obv11
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1  34.6  26.2  43.1 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 2     2     1  18.7  15.5  23.4 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 3     3     1  NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 4     3     1  20.0  15.5  23.4 NA    NA     1.32  2.78  1.44 NA    NA    NA   
 5     3     1  NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 6     3     1  NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     1.51
 7     6     1  16.7  16.0  23.4  0.19 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 8     6     1  NA    NA    NA   NA    NA     1.22  1.4   0.97  1.93  2.35  1.51
 9     6     1  19.3  16.4  25.8 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
10     7     1  23.8  18.6  28.6 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
11    12     2  28.8  24.4  39.7 NA    NA     1.13  1.89  1.32  2.46  3.21 NA   
12    13     2  24.6  19.6  29.4  0.16 NA     3.23  3.23  2.27 NA    NA    NA   
13    14     2  18.4  15.5  24.8 NA    NA     2.27  3.78  1.13  3.46  4.91  2.78
14    15     2  NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
15    15     2  25.8  24.4  39.7 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
16    16     2  NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA     1.89  2.99 NA    NA    NA   
17    16     2  22.1  17.3  26.9 NA    NA    NA     2.57  0.94 NA    NA     1.51
18    16     2  NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ! It is advised here to post at least a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you better. On top of it, we ask people that post questions, what they have tried so far and where we can help them. So could you please edit your question and add some of these details ? Thank you

Comment: How do you define "more than 25% of the observation"? In terms of number of observations? Relative to the sum of observations? Relative to the mean of observations? Statistically speaking, you could consider to summarise each ORG into a single average of observations.